# I want to write a batch file which will search entire registry for a particular key & then delete all it's occurences

Tags: batch-file, registry

I want to write a batch file which will search entire registry for a particular key & then delete all it's occurrences?It should ask user for input & then delete all occurrences.

Comment: have you checked the REG command?

Comment: This will be a very complex batch file because of the amount and varied types of data in the registry. I believe this would be better completed through a vbscript.